# R function that evaluates numerics into the name of the given number

Tags: r

For example I'm looking for a function that with similar functionality to the example below

```
numNam(1234)
>> "1 thousand, 2 hundred, and 34"
```

Does anyone know if this exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `words` function from the english package on CRAN should do what you want approximately.  It's styled a bit differently than your example output but should accomplish your goal.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/english/english.pdf